# Absoluteness of definability

Tags: set-theory

Let $M,N$ be models of set theory such that $M$ is a submodel of $N$.

Assume that there exists a formula of set theory which defines some set $X^M$ in $M$ (say $X^M$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies certain first-order properties).
If we consider $N$, then does the same formula still define $X^N$ in $N$ and $X^N$ has the same properties in $N$ as $X^M$ in $M$?

Comment: Frankly, your edit isn't very sensible, since what does $X^N$ mean except, "the thing in $N$ satisfying the given definition," where one has fixed a definition of $X$ in $M$. So of course they are defined by the same formula, and in this sense the answer is affirmative. (But note that the meaning of $X^N$ can depend on which definition of $X$ one uses in $M$, as equivalent definitions in $M$ can become inequivalent in $N$, and lead to different instantiations of $X^N$.) But as has now been pointed out, this doesn't mean that $X^N$ and $X^M$ necessarily have many properties in common.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is still no, and still for trivial reasons, even after the edit. Suppose, for example, that $M$ satisfies $V=L$.  Consider the formula saying that if $V=L$ then $X=\mathbb R$ while if $V\neq L$ then $X=\varnothing$.  So in $M$, this formula defines the set of all reals, whereas in an extension $N$  of $M$ where $V\neq L$, the same formula defines the empty set. So $X^N$ has very different properties in $N$ than $X^M$ has in $M$.

The same trick can be used whenever $M$ and $N$ are not elementarily equivalent.

Comment: One can equally just take $X=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb R^L$, which is empty in $L$ but non-empty otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The set of real numbers $X=\mathbb{R}^M$ in $M$ is definable in $M$, but using the defining formula of "being a real" in $N$ will give the reals $\mathbb{R}^N$ of $N$, which can be different. Different models of set theory can have different sets of real numbers.

Comment: See my edit please.